# How do you authenticate against a CouchDB server when using the couchrest gem?

Tags: ruby, couchdb

When using the CouchRest gem, how do you authenticate with a couchdb database that has been somewhat secured with roles (so it is not public)? I want to be able to save/destroy documents This is *not* using Rails--just a .rb file or in irb.

With the CouchDB gem, this was easy to do by passing the user/pwd into the Server instantiation. If the CouchRest gem is so much better, why is this not intuitive? Do I need to resort to raw curl calls and/or cookie-based auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer I found is that you can put the auth info in the url:

```
require 'couchrest'

db = CouchRest.database("http://exampleuser:examplepassword@localhost:5984/exampledb")
```

I'll research some more since there's probably a way to do this with hashing or something, so the auth doesn't go in plaintext. I'd still like to know how you would do the cookie or OAuth the CouchDB docs mention using the couchrest gem, so I'll put that here too, if I find it.

Comment: Works, but does not really answer the question. I am using this as a work around now, but still would like to see a better way to do this